# MSBUILD Run NCover Against Matched Projects

Tags: msbuild, ncover

I am using MSBuild and am getting all test projects using a regex on the project name, like this.

```
<RegexMatch Input="@(AllProjects)" Expression="(.)*Test(.)*">
    <Output  TaskParameter="Output" ItemName="UnitTestProjects"/>
</RegexMatch>
```

I now want to use @(UnitTestProjects) and pass them all to NCover to check that the tests are all giving 100% coverage.

To do this on a single project, I do something like this:

```
<Target Name="Coverage">
    <NCover TestRunnerExe="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.8\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"
        TestRunnerArgs="&quot;C:\SomeProject\bin\SomeProject.dll&quot; &quot;C:\SomeProject\bin\SomeProjectTest.dll&quot;"
        WorkingDirectory="C:\SomeProject\bin\"
        AppendTrendTo="coverage.trend"
        OnlyAssembliesWithSource="True"
        ProjectName="SomeProjectCoverage"    />
</Target>
```

How do I effectively use @(UnitTestProjects) in the context of this NCover target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For batching your `@(UnitTestProjects)` your Target will have to use it like this:

```
<Target Name="Coverage">
    <NCover TestRunnerExe="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.8\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"
    TestRunnerArgs="&quot;%(UnitTestProjects.Identity)&quot; &quot;%(UnitTestProjects.Identity)&quot;"

<!--
If you receive the Task Output (*Test.dll) you will have to extract
the working dir path
-->
    WorkingDirectory="C:\SomeProject\bin\"
    AppendTrendTo="coverage.trend"
    OnlyAssembliesWithSource="True"
<!--
... the same thing applies to finding out the current project name
from your Task Ouput.
-->
    ProjectName="SomeProjectCoverage"    />
</Target>
```

A more reliable solution would be, to provide a list of TaskItems, holding metadata about your (Test)project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TestProject Include="MyProject1.Test.dll">
        <TestProjectName>MyProject1</TestProjectName>
        <MyTestProjectWorkingDir>C:\MyProject1\bin</MyTestProjectWorkingDir>
    </TestProject>
    <TestProject Include="MyProject2.Test.dll">
        <TestProjectName>MyProject2</TestProjectName>
        <MyTestProjectWorkingDir>C:\MyProject2\bin</MyTestProjectWorkingDir>
    </TestProject>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Coverage">
    <NCover TestRunnerExe="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.8\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"
    TestRunnerArgs="&quot;%(TestProject.Identity)&quot; &quot;%(TestProject.Identity)&quot;"
    WorkingDirectory="%(TestProject.MyTestProjectWorkingDir)"
    AppendTrendTo="coverage.trend"
    OnlyAssembliesWithSource="True"
    ProjectName="%(TestProject.MyTestProjectName)"    />
</Target>
```

Your question suggests that you are looking for an automated approach which will allow you to add new test projects without having to maintain a configuration list of TaskItems.

Since it would be quite difficult, to extract all the information needed to feed your NCover Task maybe a semi-automated approach might work for you.

You could add an import to your test project which will feed your global test project ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- add existing ItemGroup -->
    <TestProject Include="@(TestProject)" />

    <!-- add project itself -->
    <TestProject Include="MyProject1.Test.dll">
        <TestProjectName>MyProject1</TestProjectName>
        <MyTestProjectWorkingDir>C:\MyProject1\bin</MyTestProjectWorkingDir>
    </TestProject>
</ItemGroup>
```

The usage in your NCover Task will be the same as above.

This way your master build script doesn't need to know about any specific test project; it just processes your ItemGroup "TestProject".

Comment: Hi Filburt. I'm looking for answers specifically on passing the collection of unit test projects to NCover.

Comment: @Sohnee See my updated answer with an actual example for your NCover task and a maybe more practicable solution.

Comment: Hi Filburt - thanks for updating the answer - looks muck more like what I'm after. I'll give it a spin.

Comment: I have adapted your ideas - so thank you for the head start on this. By using the output of the unit test builds, you can pass in all of the unit test assemblies... more here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201102/Blog/Adding-An-NCover-Target-To-MSBuild-To-Get-Code-Coverage/

Comment: @Sohnee Ahhh ... the linked article makes it clear. Processing the results of the build is probably the smartest way. And by the looks NCover accepts a collection of Items to process - but you will loose reporting on a per project basis. Glad I could help anyway.

Comment: @Filburt - that's the essence of it - the HTML output lets you drill down per-assembly, you might do things a bit differently if you weren't generating the HTML reports. Thanks for your help.